# How to turn list items into unicode without losing structure of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that is created with BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to change the list items from a NavigableString into Unicode, but when I try to loop through the list it has no impact, but if I call unicode on the list it becomes unicode.

If I do this it does not change the items into unicode:

```
for i in D:
    unicode(i)
```

If I do this it seems to turn the entire list into unicode and I can no longer iterate through items:

```
D = unicode(D)
```

Is there a way I can just turn the list items into unicode so I can do other things like convert them into strings, run .replace() etc.?

Comment: You are not assigning the result to anything... you can create a new list with a list comprehension, e.g. `D = [unicode(i) for i in D]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you aren't assigning your `unicode` casts to any variables. That is why the original list remains unchanged.

Your second example doesn't work because you have to apply `unicode` to each list item, not the list itself.

Use a list comprehension to create a new list from the old one, processing each item with `unicode`:

```python
D = [unicode(item) for item in D]
```

Alternatively, you can use `D = map(unicode, D)`. Note that this syntax only works on python 2.x, which is what you appear to be using.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @user3294779 No problem! Also as a friendly reminder I'd like to encourage you to embrace Python 3.x. Don't get left behind in 2020! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for count,i in enumerate(D):
    D[count]=unicode(i)
```

You need to assign it to an index.